# Creation and Anihilation Operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, operators, hilbert-space

Consider the following expressions:

1. $$ \langle \Psi | a_{i_1} a_{i_2} a_{i_3}^* a_{i_4}^* | \Psi\rangle$$
2. $$ \langle \Psi | a_{i_1}^* a_{i_2} a_{i_3}^* a_{i_4} | \Psi\rangle$$

where in the first case we are dealing with bosons and in the last we are dealing with fermions.

My problem is how to actually calculate this. Because thus far I've been doing it by ear (i.e look at the possible cases in each case and obtain a value). Take for instance the first case: We have possibly $i_1=i_2=i_3=i_4$, $i_1=i_3$,$i_2=i_4$ or $i_1=i_4$,$i_2=i_3$

and thus obtain a result. But how do I do this without actually assuming these things? because in the second case it becomes rather troublesome because of the - signs arising from it being fermions.

If someone could actually post the example for the second one on how to solve it I'd appreciate it. The first one I think I'll be able to understand from seeing the second.

EDIT

In the second case, we have 3 possible cases:

1. i1=i2, i4=i3, i1=/=i3. Then, we get a contribution $n_{i_3}n_{i_1}$. (there are no -1 factors because it's just the usual number operator)
2. all i's are the same: $n_i^2$
3. i1=i4, i3=i2, i2=/=i1. How do I do this? Because choosing the normal representation implies the possible appearance of minus signs depending on whether i1

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know how to evaluate the second amplitude? I assume that the a's are oscillators and that they satisfy
$$
\{ a_i, a_j^* \} = \delta_{ij}
$$
You start by normal ordering the terms inside the bracket (put all creation operators to the left). Using the commutations relations you find, 
$$
a^*_{i_1} a_{i_2} a^*_{i_3} a_{i_4} = a_{i_1}^* (\delta_{i_2 i_3}-a_{i_3}^*a_{i_2}) a_{i_4} = -a_{i_1}^* a_{i_3}^* a_{i_2} a_{i_1} + a_{i_1}^*a_{i_4}\delta_{i_2i_3}
$$
Now you just act with the oscillators on the state $\vert \psi \rangle$. If it happens to be the ground state, annihilated by all lowering operators, then its zero (which you could see even before normal ordering) otherwise you have to compute the action explicitly.

I'm not sure if this is what your question was about, but this is the standard procedure to evaluate brackets of oscillators.

Comment: Useful trick to compute vacuum expectation values (faster) is to look at the expression between vacuums and: 1) realize that if the number of creation operators is not equal to number of annihilation operators, then the expression is zero. 2) If numbers are equal, then just clip every annihilation operator with some creation operator being TO THE RIGHT of it. Then enumerate every possible pairing (just draw clips above the pairs). Finally, realize that every clip mean $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: I forgot,  additional factor for a clip is $(-1)^l$ where $l$ is number of creation operators skipped by the clip. This description might sound very complicated (more complicated than (anti)commutating operators to the left or right), but it really simplificates things if you have more operators in your VEV.

Comment: My question was not quite that. I'll edit the original question